# mp3 cutter android

Tags: java, android

Following code is working fine for me. Since I am working with android ,I can't use audiostream class.

```
           File correct = new File("data1.mp3");
           File file =new File("data.mp3");
               correct.createNewFile();
           FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(correct);

           byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];


           for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){

               in.read(buffer, 0, 2048);

               out.write(buffer, 0, 2048);

           }

           in.close();
           out.close();
```

Now if I run following code , its giving error and not working

```
               correct.createNewFile();
           FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(correct);

           byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];

           in.skip(2048);
           for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){

               in.read(buffer, 0, 2048);

               out.write(buffer, 0, 2048);

           }

           in.close();
           out.close();
```

Same thing here , When I run this code its giving error

```
               correct.createNewFile();
           FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(correct);

           byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];


           for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){

               in.read(buffer, 0, 2048);
               in.skip(2048);
               out.write(buffer, 0, 2048);

           }

           in.close();
           out.close();
```

So my actual question is that how do you specify correct offset and get frames copied to a new mp3 file? How to get the size of the frame ? Is it necessary to have some starting important frames must be copied?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the frames of an audio in android, you have to implement the clipper.
look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/source/browse/trunk/?r=66#trunk/src/com/ringdroid)